# Membership receipt email template not showing correct dates

Tags: civimember, email

Updated membership start and end dates, to reflect the upcoming/current registration period. The email receipt sent out on purchases still uses the old dates.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the upcoming/current registration period'?

Answer (score 2):

The dates are only updated when the payment is completed. If you allow for offline payment (e.g. cheque), then the dates are not updated yet when the invoice email is sent.

In that case, the subject of the message should be `invoice` rather than `receipt`.

As a workaround, you might want to remove the dates from the template or create tokens but those template are rather complex to edit (html + smarty logic). If you feel confident about editing those templates, you can find them in :

- menu `Mailings` -> `Message templates`
- tab `System Workflow Messages`
- `Memberships - Receipt (on-line)` -> `Edit` (and possibly Memberships - Signup and Renewal Receipts (off-line)` if you want to change the behavior when you create/renew the membership as an admin)

[image]

[image]